# For help an inequality that for large $n$, whether $\frac{n\choose \big[\frac{n}{2\log_2n}\big]-1}{(\sqrt{2})^n}\geq(1+\beta)^n$ for some $\beta>0$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, functional-inequalities, approximate-integration

Can anyone help me to prove that for large $n$

whether $$\dfrac{n\choose \big[\frac{n}{2\log_2n}\big]-1}{(\sqrt{2})^n}\geq(1+\beta)^n$$  for some $\beta>0$ where  and $\big[x\big]$ denotes the integer part of $x$, for example, letting $x=5.3222$, then $\big[x\big]=5$.

Which is equivalent to ask whether $ n\choose \big[\frac{n}{2\log_2n}\big]-1 $$>(\sqrt{2}+\beta)^n$ for some $\beta>0$.

Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: You at minimum need $1+\beta<\sqrt2$ because otherwise you’d have $$\binom{n}k\geq 2^n$$

Comment: we only need $(1+\beta)>1$, so $\beta=0.1$ or $\beta=0.01$ are both ok

Comment: But they say you stated it implies you want it true for all $\beta,$ not for some $\beta.$ You should say at the beginning, “For some $\beta>0,$ …”

Comment: Thanks for reminder, modify it

Comment: You can simplify this expression by removing the division and just want it to be $>(\sqrt2+\beta)^n$ for some $\beta.$

Answer (score 2):

This is not true however; $\sqrt[3m]{2m} = \left(e^{\ln (2m) }\right)^{\frac{1}{3m}}$ $=e^{\frac{\ln(2m)}{3m}} \rightarrow 1$ for $m \rightarrow \infty$ which is what is happening here for $m =\log n$. This gives
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left(\frac{\sqrt[3\log n]{2\log n}}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n < \left(\frac{1.1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^n =0.$$

**This still holds true even for the new question:**

$${n \choose k} =\frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!}$$
$$\le \frac{n^k}{k!} \le 2ke^k\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^k,$$ the latter a consequence of Stirling's Inequality.

For $k\in \theta\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)$ then:
$${n \choose k} \le$$
$$ke^k\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^k = ke^k(\theta(\log n))^{\theta\left(\frac{n}{\log n}\right)}$$ $$\le ke^k\left(2^{\theta(\log_2\log_2n)}\right)^{\theta\left(\frac{n}{2\log n}\right)}=2^{o(n)}.$$

Thus, $${n \choose k} = 2^{o(n)} \text{ for } k = \frac{n}{2\log n} \pm 1 $$ and dividing both sides of this by $2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ gives

$$2^{-\frac{n}{2}}{n \choose k} =2^{o(n)}2^{-\frac{n}{2}} < 1$$ for such $k$, which shows that the inequality in this question cannot be.

Something similar can be concluded for any $k\in o(n)$ infact.

Comment: @SeekForHelp this is a completely different question.

Comment: Similar result holds

Comment: you forgot $\frac{n\choose k-1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}$

Comment: No, if you divide both sides of ${n\choose k}=2^{o(n)}$ by $2^{n/2}$ you see that your inequality cannot be.

Comment: You should be able to see that the result still holds.

Comment: your proof is incorrect. because I have ask another question that $\log_2\left(n\choose \big[\frac{n}{2\log_2n}\big]-1\right)>cn$ for some constant $c>0$.  So , we can easily get $n \choose \big[\frac{n}{2\log_2 n}\big]-1$$>2^{cn}=2^{O(n)}$ rather than $2^{o(n)}$. But the lower-bound is too coarse。 My question is to ask whether we can get more accurate result